# Java - Waiting data from multiple clients in a multithreaded server

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a multithreaded server that waits for a set of parameters sampled from multiple clients and sent to the server. Each client periodically sends its parameters to the server thread to which it is connected. Another thread (possibly ServerManager that instantiates the individual ThreadServer for managing the connection with the client) must wait for the reception of the parameters from all clients and only after executing the rest. What could be the synchronization mechanism most appropriate to analyze the reception of the updated parameters from all clients connected to the server side (assuming to have a fixed number of clients)? The most obvious solution would be to conduct a polling on an array indicating the current status of the parameters ... but I think it would be better with condition variables, for example, or something like that. Thanks!

Comment: does the Phaser meet your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Pass all threads listening for client data a reference to a `java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue` to write the client data into and collect/analyse the client data in a Listener/Polling thread (referencing the same queue).

Answer (score 0):

If it's truly an issue of having Thread A waiting for Threads B, C, and D, and that you don't have to worry or track B sending twice (thus 2 potential transactions starting up), then you can use a CountdownLatch. As each client updates the "global" parameter structure, they count the latch down. When the latch goes to zero, the waiting thread is release and can go on its merry way.

You need to recreate the latch for each batch, and this only works for a single transaction (otherwise, if naively constructed, Thread B can count down the latch twice). So you'll need some other constraint to prevent that from happening.